# Why my code in VB is not working?

Tags: vb.net

So the task is: 
Write a program that contains a text box, a list box and a command button. Put a label above the text box that tells the user to type a number from 1 to 10 inside the text box. When the user clicks the command button, check the text box for a valid number and issue an error message box if the number isn't inside the expected range or in case of empty input. If the user entered a valid number, assign it to the integer variable n and use a For...Next loop to accumulate the sum of the first n elements of an array declared with the statement Dim numList() as Integer = {2, 4, 10, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4} Display the sum in the list box.

```
Private Sub bCom_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bCom.Click
    Dim n As Integer = CInt(tNum.Text)

    If CDbl(tNum.Text) > 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Number from 1 to 10")
        tNum.Focus()
    End If

    Dim numList() As Integer = {2, 4, 10, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4}
    Dim sum As Integer
    For Each n As Integer In numList
        sum += n
    Next

    lOut.Items.Add(sum)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: In what way isn't it working?  Incorrect result, error?

Comment: It keeps giving the sum of all the numbers and not including the (n) variable e.g. value of the tNum

Comment: its because you have a variable declared as n, and also in your for each loop, another variable declared as n. try to use different names for your variables

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because the `n` in the `For Each` loop hides a variable in the enclosing block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `for each` loop instead of a `for` loop, so you iterate over each element in the array, not just the first `n` ones.

You should use something like:

```
For x = 0 To n - 1 
    sum += numList(x)
Next
```

Some more problems:

- No need to convert the text to double if you already converted it to an integer the line before.
- You should use `Int32.TryParse` in case the user enters something that is not a number.
- You just check if the number is greater 10, but not if it is smaller than 1.
- If the number is invalid, you display a message to the user, then you just keep going on, 
  but you should exit your method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to sum the first n digits of the array numList.
If this is the case then you need to change your loop code in this way

```
For x = 0 To n -1 
    sum += numList(x)
Next
```

Use x as the indexer to the numList array, start at the first element of the array (x=0) and stop when the indexer has reached the value of n - 1

With this you could satisfy the requirements exactly how they have been asked.
If you wish you could also show an elegant approach using LinQ without an explict loop

```
sum = numList.Take(n).Sum()
```

However, before going fancy, it is better that you remove some obvious errors in your code

```
if Not Int32.TryParse(tNum.Text, n) Then
     MessageBox.Show("Error......")
     tNum.Focus()
     Return
End If

if n < 1 OrElse n > 10 Then
     MessageBox.Show("Error......")
     tNum.Focus()
     Return
End if
```

And do not use the old fashioned function like CInt e CDbl that are kept only for compatibility with VB6. Use the newest methods like Int32.TryParse, Convert.ToInt32 etc...

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you need an indexed For..Loop, not a ForEach loop.
You might also consider moving the "is it a valid number" logic to a separate function.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
        'is the number valid?
        Dim n As Integer = -1
        If IsInputValid(txbInput.Text, n) Then
            Dim sum As Integer = 0

            'declare an array of numbers
            Dim numList() As Integer = {2, 4, 10, 5, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4}

            'accumulate the sum of the first N elements of the array
            For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
                sum += numList(i)
            Next

            'refresh the listbox with the sum
            lbxOutput.Items.Clear()
            lbxOutput.Items.Add(sum.ToString)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 1 and 10")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function IsInputValid(input As String, ByRef validnumber As Integer) As Boolean
        'input must be a number between 1 and 10
        'if it is valid, assign it to the byref validNumber parameter.
        Dim i As Integer = -1
        If Integer.TryParse(input, i) Then
            If i >= 1 AndAlso i <= 10 Then
                validnumber = i
                Return True
            End If
        End If
        validnumber = i
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```